# Cluster CPT posts to users based on ACF value from their profile on dashboard

Tags: custom-post-types, advanced-custom-fields, user-meta, dashboard

I have added an ACF in each user profile which contain a list of cities.
Each user select a city he is in
The goal would be that only people from the same city will be able to access the same posts they have created only on the Wordpress Dashboard.

So they won t see other other "city" posts...

Any idea how I can implement that ?

Thank you in advance,